# How to deploy hyperledger fabric cluster on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, hyperledger-fabric

Currently, the Fabric system consists of components running in multiple containers, which will be a challenge to maintain all those containers, thus I want to use some powerful containers management platform such as Kubernetes, to deploy Fabric.

Could anybody help ?

Answer (score 2):

Properly configuring and deploying Hyperledger Fabric components to Kubernetes is not trivial. And also is only one part of the puzzle. Populating the Fabric network regarding `channels` and `chaincodes` is also as important as launching the Fabric network. In my opinion, this second part is highly overlooked.

This GitHub repository called [Hyperledger Fabric meets Kubernetes](https://github.com/APGGroeiFabriek/PIVT) contains a couple of Helm charts to:

- Configure and launch the whole HL Fabric network, either:

  - A simple one, one peer per organization and Solo orderer
  - Or scaled up one, multiple peers per organization and Kafka or Raft orderer
- Populate the network declaratively:

  - Create the channels, join peers to channels, update channels for Anchor peers
  - Install/Instantiate all chaincodes, or some of them, or upgrade them to newer version
- Add new peer organizations to an already running network declaratively
- Backup and restore the state of whole network

Tested against Fabric versions 1.4.1 to 1.4.4 and just works fine.

**PS:** I'm the author of these Helm charts. As mentioned in our repo, we had implemented these Helm charts for our project's needs, and as the results looks very promising, decided to share the source code with the HL Fabric community. Hopefully it will fill a large gap!

I can confirm, we are using the very same Helm charts in all our environments and CI/CD pipelines since May 2019 without any issues, and will go to production in early 2020.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy Fabric on pure kubernetes environment, this could be help https://medium.com/@zhanghenry/how-to-deploy-hyperledger-fabric-on-kubernetes-1-a2ceb3ada078